# Change CSS when grid API boolean is === 'true'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid which has the ability to add a groupedHeader, so a header which can expand and collapse a selection of sub-headers.  On the grid's API is a boolean `gridAPI.expanded` which returns true if expanded and false if not.

I'm trying to adjust the width of the div holding the grid based on this boolean.

I've tried using `ng-style` with `ng-if` in my div but it doesn't pick up on the boolean (which I've put on the scope):

```
<div ng-if ='gridAPI.expanded === true' ng-style="{width:1720px}"></div>
```

The only way to know if the grid has been expanded is with this boolean.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<div ng-style="gridAPI.expanded ? {width: '1720px'} : {}"></div>
```

Comment: @xeon48: do you see jquery here?

Comment: oh apologies I'm fairly new to javascript, I was under the impression `?` was jquery only

Comment: but this is because you've attached the action to a button - there is no way to tell whether the header has been expanded other than when the boolean changes.

Comment: how exactly that boolean changes if not within a digest cycle?

Comment: finally got this working, your answer and plunker helped a lot, although i did need to add a listener to detect the change.  thanks